# npm vs node version numbers

Tags: node.js, npm

I just downloaded the latest version of node.js, which at the time of this post is 8.11

Yet my npm version# was still on 5.x, so I ran 
npm install -g npm

Now, when I run npm -v, I see 6.1.0

Are the version#'s for Node and npm usually different?

Comment: @Downvoter This should not have been downvoted, coming from different backgrounds like VS.NET, people like us never know there is an _npm_ which is different from _node_ ,

Comment: As another VS.Net developer myself it took me a while to figure out that when you speak of npm, you are actually NOT referring to Nuget Package Management which is something that we use everyday, unlike Node Package Manager :-P

Answer (score 19, accepted):

NPM is `Node Package Manager`. It is the official package manager for Node. That is why NPM is downloaded with Node, but they are 2 totally different pieces of software and evolve separately.

Comment: Why would angular require only a few specific versions of npm but a whole slew of node versions? I would think the goal would be to at least match the version of npm that comes with a given version of nodejs. I have a case where angular requires node > 10 (using 16) but npm is 6. I have npm 8.

Comment: @BrianReinhold Node is the engine that will run Javascript. NPM installs the dependencies and sets up your project. If Angular only needs the Javascript features that come with Node 10, or use a transpiler to enable that retro compatibility, they will only require Node 10 or above. However, if their install process requires some features from NPM 6+, they will need the user (you) to have that version. Since anyone can install any NPM version (`npm i -g npm@version`) they can be separate.

Answer (score 4):

> Are the version#'s for Node and npm usually different?

In short, yes, they aren't the same thing - NPM is a package manager and Node is a runtime and both are developed separately with different release cycles.